# How to make point clickable

Tags: jquery, flot

I use flot to create a 1 line graph, works perfect, but i just can't get my points clickable

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var options = {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        points: { show: true }

    },
    grid:{hoverable: true, clickable:true}
};

$(function() {
    var rvline = ['.$js_rv_values.']; // data generated by php
    $.plot("#rvgraph", [  { data: rvline}], options);

    $("#rvgraph").on("plotclick",function(event,pos,item){
        if(item){ alert(item.series.data[item.dataIndex]);}
    });
});



</script>
```

I have read the info on plots'website, but copuld not find the solution. Also not on Google flot group.
added grid option, which do work, because on hover it get a little bit highligthed circle around it.

I wanted to test the clickevent, but eventually, i want to show a link, based on the array index or gameID (third value of a point)

Generated values look like: 
var rvline = [[1,1487,"1241417"],[2,1474,"1241418"], etcetera...

Comment: Your code works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/376jJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the grid 'clickable' option to true, as described in the [Customizing the Grid](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) section of the docs.

Comment: I already added that option. I dont know why, but now it works. Like Mark showed in jsFiddle. Thank you both!

Comment: Oh, sorry, somehow I didn't notice those.